# Kafka inter-region latency too high

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and I'm experimenting with a single region Kafka deployment where webservers from different regions [ IN, EU, US etc.. ] push to a centralized Kafka deployment [ US ]. However the throughput and latency from US to US is very low and performs very well while other regions suffer from high latency. I'm not sure why this is happening. Here are my configuration and test results.

BROKER CONFIG

```
broker.id=1
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.20.1.17:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/datadrive/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=zk1:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
message.max.bytes=10485760
```

I have a very simple setup with 1 broker [ 4core 16GB ram ] and 1 zookeeper [ 2core 8GB ram ]

I'm using the `kafka-producer-perf-test.sh` script included with Kafka for performance testing. Here's the command [ same command used from all regions ]

`./kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic 500B-1M --num-records 10000000 --throughput -1 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=broker1:9092 max.request.size=10485760 batch.size=1000000 acks=0 linger.ms=5000 request.timeout.ms=300000 --record-size 500`

Here are the performance benchmarking results.

1. US
   [image]
2. Europe
   [image]

As you can see, the latency from EU is somewhere about 25s which is too high. I've also tried using a larger batch size and larger linger.ms but they have the same performance.

I've also considered regional deployments, but our scale isn't so high to have a regional deployment yet.

Do let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: This is expected results. Your remote producers are pushing over the internet and going through multiple hops. Ideally, you do do regional deployments, then use tools like MirrorMaker or Confluent Cluster Links to get data in a centralized location (assuming you really need that)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm using private IP for advertised.listeners . Shouldn't that make it faster since it's routed through private network?
Even if it's pushing through public internet, the average latency between US and IN is about 200ms, but 25s for a batch seems too extensive.

Comment: I suggest testing with `iperf3` to test network speeds first, then worry about Kafka client properties